# Is there a way to show indentation lines in Visual C# 2005?

Tags: c#, add-in

Is there an Add-In or a setting? Would be nice...

Comment: Next time, try using google for questions like that.

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't find the solution and wanted to ask here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but also helpfull thank you!

Comment: What are you looking for?  Update your question, possibly with a screen shot.

Comment: I wanted vertical lines between { and }, these are horizontal lines in every row...

Answer (score 0):

Try Edit|Advanced|View Whitespace (Ctrl-E, S), it will show indentation dots.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for an indentation symbol or something.....  if that's the case, there isn't anything like that built into Visual Studio, as far as I know